# Removing jump discontinuity from a tricky function.

Tags: calculus, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions, piecewise-continuity

I have the function $\cos(x)\lfloor x \rfloor$ which I would like to make continuous without changing the derivative where it exists or the values approaching 0 from the right side. I can do this by subtracting a piecewise constant function from it. My trouble here is that I do not know what that function should be.

I believe it is:

$$\sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{i=0} \cos(x)$$

But I am unsure as to how would I would reduce it further or if it is correct. Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean to "make" it continuous? Why not subtract itself from it? - You may also be interested in $\sin(\pi x)\lfloor x\rfloor$, which is already continuos ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe I'm misunderstanding what a step function/what the questioner is asking, but I don't think $\cos x\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a step function, so they can't subtract that. They want a step function $f(x)$ such that $\cos x\lfloor x\rfloor-f(x)$ is continuous. The summation they put above indeed makes this function continuous for positive $x$, but they are having trouble simplifying it to show that it is just a step function.

Comment: for $x$ not an integer, the derivative of $\cos(x) \lfloor x \rfloor$ is $-\sin(x) \lfloor x \rfloor$, so once the jumps are removed, you get $-\int \lfloor x \rfloor\sin(x)) dx = \ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea ist almost correct, namely to substract the jumps from the function. Obviously, $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R,\ x\mapsto\cos(x)[x]$ has jumps only at $x=x_0\in\mathbb N$, and at each those points we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_0-}f(x)=\cos(x_0)(x_0-1),\qquad \lim_{x\to x_0+}=\cos(x_0)x_0.
\end{align*}
Thus, the hight of each jump is $\cos(x_0)$, so
\begin{align*}
F(x):=\cos(x)[x]-\sum_{k=1}^{[x]}\cos(k)
\end{align*}
is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

To make it continuous in all of $\mathbb R$, you can do the same trick for negative values of $x$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
F(x):=\cos(x)[x]-\sum_{k=1}^{[x]}\cos(k)+\sum_{k=0}^{[-x]}\cos(k)
\end{align*}
is continuous in $\mathbb R$. Here, a sum $\sum_{k=a}^b...$ is meant to be 0, if $b<a$.

Comment: It's pedantic, but worth noting, that if the domain of $f$ is instead allowed to be $\Bbb R$, there is no "canonical" way to do this construction: you can also subtract an arbitrary constant and the derivative remains the same. You might complain that if you take a totally arbitrary constant, the new function might *never* agree with the old function. That complaint is reasonable, but for most functions there are still infinitely many constants that are as reasonable as the one produced using the method provided.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I added a little more detail for negative values.

Comment: For me a finite sum $\sum_{k=a}^b x_k=\sum_{k\in K}x_k$, where $K=\{k\in\mathbb Z\ |\ a\leq k\leq b\}$. If $b<a$, then $K$ is empty, and then the sum is by definition equal to 0.
This particular sums habe indeed a closed form in terms of sin, cot and cos (Mathematica says so), but this is a specialty of your problem. Usually, there is no closed form.